# How to dig a multi-line matrix assignment from history?

Tags: matlab

A few days ago, I did a long assignment of data into a variable:

```
m = [ 0 0 0
      1 0 3
      2 6 9
      ...
      59 2 5];
```

This was a 60x3 matrix of data, which I copy-pasted from somewhere, and I don't have the data anymore. So the only place I have these numbers is Matlab history.

Today, I want to do additional calculations on these numbers, so I want to load them into a variable again. However, when I press the <kbd>up</kbd> key, I can repeat the following previous command:

```
m = [ 0 0 0
```

This is not enough. How can I get the whole multi-line assignment from history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your command history and press ctrl+F and enter your search phrase. Make sure to select the option to search from the beginning of the command instead of anywhere.

[image: Picture example]

Then, you can click on the bracket to the left of the search results to select the whole command at once.

Comment: Note a user may need to go to Home > Layout > Command History > Docked to emulate your image.